# Responsive images: Picture element using width and height of fallback <img> tag when using AVIF/WEBP

Tags: html, css, responsive, webp, avif

I have a website that I have made responsive and utilise the `<picture>` element to serve up webp, avif and have a png fallback for older browsers. It should look like this (Chrome/Safari):

[image: Normal]

For some reason, certain browsers (Firefox 94 on desktop and mobile, Safari on iOS 14< as examples) will load the AVIF format of the image, but will use the explicit `width` and `height` from the fallback `<img>` tag I have inside the `<picture>` element, resulting in a warped image.

[image: Stretched]

The site in question is: https://blah.cloud/now (pull the browser to <768px wide to see the problem).

The code I'm doing the image selection with is as below:

```html
<picture>
<source media="(min-width: 768px)" srcset="/images/logo-title.avif" type="image/avif" alt="logo" width="245" height="34">
<source media="(min-width: 768px)" srcset="/images/logo-title.webp" type="image/webp" alt="logo" width="245" height="34">
<source srcset="/images/logo.avif" type="image/avif" alt="logo" width="65" height="65">
<source srcset="/images/logo.webp" type="image/webp" alt="logo" width="65" height="65">
<img src="/images/logo-title.png" alt="logo" aria-label="logo" width="245" height="34">
</picture>
```

The reason for the explicit `width` and `height` is for Google PSI to avoid CLS.

I'm kind of at a loss here as to why this behaviour happens - if it is pulling the avif/webp image, and I've confirmed that it is, it should use the `width` and height`associated with that`` element?

Any ideas greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no `width` and `height` attribute for a `<source>` element! [ [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/source#attributes) ]

You could resize your image resources instead. Then make the `<picture>` element a block element and resize it in CSS. To adjust the image do `object-fit: cover;` (or other possible options you can find on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit#syntax)) on `<img>`.

Comment: Hm, judging by that though I could use the `sizes` param on that element?

The challenge is that this is a Hugo theme I've built and I want it to be able to accept a width and heigh defined by the user in the config file, hence the `width` and `height` being defined in HTML.

I'll play with `sizes` and see if that helps.

Comment: It also appears that Safari <15 has no support for the `source` element anyway, so CSS it is I support. https://caniuse.com/?search=source

Comment: Further investigate: all browsers on iOS _must_ use webkit because of Apple's restrictions, so that explains why all iOS browsers on <iOS 15 exhibit the same behaviour.